# combine list of different lengths in PYTHON in a specific combination of values

Tags: python, list, dataframe, loops, web-scraping

I have the two following lists:

Team Lists:

```py
['FC Bayern München',
 'FC Bayern München',
 'FC Bayern München',
 'FC Bayern München',
 'FC Bayern München',
 'RasenBallsport Leipzig',
 'RasenBallsport Leipzig',
 'RasenBallsport Leipzig']
```

Missed Games List:

```py
[1.0, 8.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

What I want is the following: whenever the missed games list takes on the value "zero" I do not want that  there is a teamname, I want sth like "NA" there. the reason is that on the website I am **scraping**, no teamnames are indicated when the player did not miss any game but it actually should be NA to achieve my goal!

The results should be the following in the dataframe / tuples:

```
1.0, Bayern München 
         
8.0, Bayern München

1.0, Bayern München

0.0, NA

0.0, NA

1.0, Bayern München

1.0, Bayern München

0.0, NA

2.0, RasenBallsport Leipzig

2.0, RasenBallsport Leipzig

1.0, RasenBallsport Leipzig
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: What are you not able to do? Just do an if 0 and if it is true, break and move to the next case. Please post a specific issue and not a "How do I do this?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
team_list = [
    "FC Bayern München",
    "FC Bayern München",
    "FC Bayern München",
    "FC Bayern München",
    "FC Bayern München",
    "RasenBallsport Leipzig",
    "RasenBallsport Leipzig",
    "RasenBallsport Leipzig",
]

missed_game_list = [1.0, 8.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Missed Game": missed_game_list, "Team": np.nan})
df.loc[df["Missed Game"] != 0, "Team"] = team_list
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Missed Game                    Team
0           1.0       FC Bayern München
1           8.0       FC Bayern München
2           1.0       FC Bayern München
3           0.0                     NaN
4           0.0                     NaN
5           1.0       FC Bayern München
6           1.0       FC Bayern München
7           0.0                     NaN
8           2.0  RasenBallsport Leipzig
9           2.0  RasenBallsport Leipzig
10          1.0  RasenBallsport Leipzig
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much - my problem is solved!